# How to use JSTL in JSP: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

> I am using TomCatServer v10.1 for Java Web Development project. I am not able to use JSTL in JSP and the error is

`HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error`
`Type Exception Report`

`Message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator`

`Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.`

`Exception`

`jakarta.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator`
`org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)`
`jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)`
`org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)`
`Root Cause`

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator`
`java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`
`java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)`
`java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)`
`org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)`
`org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)`
`org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)`
`org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)`
`java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`
`java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)`
`java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)`
`Apache Tomcat/10.1.19`

[Check this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkHbz.png)

I also included jstl-1.2 jar file in the Calculator\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib folder and tried using different versions of JSTL still the problem is not solved.

Comment: Use tomcat 9 for javax.servlet, 10 for jakarta.servlet. you can have only one of those dependencies. Use them from the same servlet spec. I do not have the canonical duplicate on my phone, but this is a common duplicate.

Comment: jstl-1.2 jar is not compatible with Tomcat 10 and above. You'll need JSTL 2.0 or newer.